# Deploy Azure AD WebAPI to IIS, with Windows Authentication enabled, skips Azure AD Authentication

Tags: authentication, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have a WebAPI that I have successfully secured with Azure AD.  When I run it locally (through Visual Studio), trying to access the WebAPI end point via a browser gives me

```
Authorization has been denied for this request.
```

Which is what I would expect.  Accessing the WebAPI through a client with ADAL library works as it should.  A forms login screen pops up, and authenticates me and passes back a token, which I can then use in my WebAPI requests.

Something I wouldn't expect happens if I deploy the WebAPI to an IIS server, and have Windows Authentication enabled for the site.  When I try to hit it the IIS WebAPI end point through a browser, I get a Windows Authentication prompt.  If I successfully authenticate the Windows Authentication, the WebAPI serves the response.

I guess I would expect that the WebAPI would return the same "Authorization has been denied for this request".  Windows Authentication shouldn't authenticate me to the WebAPI if I've configured the WebAPI to use Azure AD authentication.

My question is, is this expected behaviour, and if so, why?

I can see from one perspective that the WebAPI can accept authentication from any method that I've configured.  But part of me thinks that since the Azure AD authentication is configured in the WebAPI application, and not IIS, it should take precedence.

Comment: You need to disable Windows Authentication in your virtual machine running IIS if you want Azure AD to authentication requests.  It sounds like you have everything configured correctly in your Web API. But, your host configuration (IIS) is preempting your app's configuration.

Comment: Ok, so this is the expected behaviour?  

I did try that before, and I did get Azure AD authentication requests, but I'm wondering why this is the behaviour.

Comment: Yes. When you enable Windows Auth, authentication is essentially happening at the server boundary. This happens *before* any configuration settings for your web app are taken into consideration and is the reason for the behavior you are seeing. By disabling it, you're allowing ASP.NET (and therefore your configuration) to handle the authentication for users.